# Prove that three points are aligned in the complex plane

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

So here is my problem: Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be three distinct points of affixes $z_A$, $z_B$ and $z_C$. We define $Z=\frac{z_C-z_A}{z_B-z_A}$, show that $Z$ is real if and only if the points $A$, $B$ and $C$ are aligned.

This is what I've done so far: If $Z$ is real then $Z=\overline{Z}\longrightarrow$ $\frac{z_C-z_A}{z_B-z_A}=\frac{\overline{z_C}-\overline{z_A}}{\overline{z_B}-\overline{z_A}}\longrightarrow$  $(z_C-z_A)(\overline{z_B}-\overline{z_A})=(\overline{z_C}-\overline{z_A})(z_B-z_A )$

After expand: $z_C(\overline{z_B}-\overline{z_A})-z_A\overline{z_B}=\overline{z_C}(z_B-z_A)-\overline{z_A}z_B$

And now I don't know what to do with that, I am dumb, stupid or dumb?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given is, $Z=(z_C-z_A)/(z_B-z_A)$ is real. Therefore $\arg Z =0, \pi$. Now

$$\arg Z= \arg (z_C-z_A) -\arg (z_B-z_A) \in \{ 0,\pi \}$$
$$\Rightarrow \arg (z_C-z_A) = \arg (z_B-z_A) $$
$$ \text{or,} \quad \arg (z_C-z_A) = \pi + \arg (z_B-z_A)$$

So either  $(z_C-z_A)$ has same slope as $(z_B-z_A)$ or $(z_C-z_A)$ has same slope as $-(z_B-z_A)$.

In both cases $A,B,C$ lie on same line. In first case $B,C$ lie on same side of $A$. In second case $B,C$ lie on opposite sides of $A$.

Comment: Yes thank you ! I knew I went to the wrong direction, I expected a new approach way simpler, thanks !